# ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-44): Unable to ask for ssh-userauth service

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, ssh, libssh2

I'm facing an issue while trying to connect to my Ubuntu server using `ssh2_connect()`. The specific error message I receive is:

```
ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-44): Unable to ask for ssh-userauth service
```

Here are my technical specifications:

- PHP version: 8.3.1
- Libssh2 version: 1.11.0
- Ubuntu version: 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with Docker environment.